# Show Preference Category if preference selected true

Tags: android, preference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Actions">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="Call"
        android:title="Call"
        android:defaultValue="false" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="Email"
        android:title="Email"
        android:defaultValue="false" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="Message"
        android:title="Message"
        android:defaultValue="false" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="Alert"
        android:title="Alert"
        android:defaultValue="false" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Call">
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Email">
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Message">
</PreferenceCategory>
 <PreferenceCategory android:title="Alert">
</PreferenceCategory>
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

How can I only show the preferencecategory call, if the above  swithpreference call is selected true.  Same for others ( email, message, alert ) . Thank you for help.

Comment: Try `<PreferenceCategory android:title="Call" android:dependency="Call">`. This works for preferences; I have not tried it for `PreferenceCategory`. If it works, the `Call` category will be enabled/disabled based upon the `Call` switch. If you need it truly visible/invisible, that will require Java code, and it would not seem to be a commonly-used approach. More common is having a dedicated screen for "call", with a `SwitchPreference` at the top and enabled/disabled preferences below that.

Comment: this works in enabling disabling, how can make it visible/invisible